# load data into html select when users press create button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I have problem while loading data into html select when users press or click button.
Here is the scenario:

1. There is button to create button dynamically
2. When user click that button then the form displayed
3. When the form displayed there is an html select dynamically
   showing data from database using php as a server side.

**Does anyone know how to solve the scenario number 3?**

I have used jquery to create new form but to load data into html select is really painful for me.

Comment: Create the form serverside as you expect it tobe displayed before using jquery load() ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP

something like this:

```
<?php  
$option[] = array('option1'=>'somepage1',
                  'option2'=>'somepage2',
                  'option3'=>'somepage3');

echo json_encode(array('options'=>$option)) //set output to json encode
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#create").bind('click',function(){
    $.get('somepage.php',function(data){
      $("#form").show(); //form holder
      $("#select").empty();
      $.each(data.options, function(i,val){
       $("#select").append("<option>"+val.option1+"</option>"
                          +"<option>"+val.option2+"</option>"
                          +"<option>"+val.option3+"</option>");
      });  
    },'json');
    $(this).unbind();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({url:'somepage.php'}).done(msg){
    $('#select_id').html(msg);
}
```

on page somepage.php you generate html and echo it:

```
<?
   echo '<option>something</option>';
?>
```

thats all

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this
AJAX:

```
$.post("yourPHP.php", {toSend: whatever}, function(data){
vOutput="<select>";
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    vOutput+="<opiton>"+data[i]+"</option>";
}
vOutput+="</select>"
$("#yourdiv").html(vOutput);
},'json')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get the `<select>` options via **html** (like "12..") from server, then (using jquery):

```
$.ajax({url:"index.php",
   success:function(data) {
      $("#my_select").html(data);
   }
});
```

if you get the `<select>` options via array-like values (json perhaps), then:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var values = {option1:{value:"value1",text:"text1"},option2:{value:"value2",text:"text2"},option3:{value:"value3",text:"text3"}};   // lets say these came from server (a json response)
    var d = $("#my_select")[0];
    d.length = 0;
    var c=0;
    for(var x in values) {
       d.options[c++] = new Option(values[x]["text"],values[x]["value"]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should be something like this.

```
 $('#button').click(function(){
     $('<element to show>').show();
     $('<element to load the data into>').load('my_page.php');
 });
```

Your `my_page.php`

```
<?php
$data = get_data_from_db();
foreach ($data as $d){
    echo '<option value='+ $d['value'] +'>'+ $d['text'] +'</option>';
}
?>
```